# Posicionar seta de um menu dropdown corretamente

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Adicionei uma seta aos meus menus dropdown do Bootstrap 3, porém estou com problemas na hora de posicionar a arrow corretamente abaixo do `dropdown-toggle`, segue abaixo uma imagem de demonstração:

### [image: Na esquerda é o meu cenário atual, com a arrow mal posicionada. Na direita é como eu gostaria de deixar.]

Na esquerda é o meu cenário atual, com a arrow mal posicionada (`right: 45%`). Na direita é como eu gostaria de deixar.

Alguém pode me ajudar nisso? Abaixo meu código CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma vez tive esse problema também. O que eu fiz foi justamente alterar a propriedade '`right: __'`.

Ela determina a distância do objeto da lateral direita, nesse caso, está 45% longe da borda direita. Tente diminuir até obter o resultado que você deseja. Acredito que com '`right:10%;`' você consiga o resultado desejado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Edit: Se você quiser uma precisão maior, pode usar '`px`' ao invés de '`%`'.

Pois imagine o seguinte: em uma tela pequena e grande ele estará '`10%`' longe da lateral, porém esse `%` é diferente em um celular e em um monitor `1080p`. Já com o valor em `px` ele será constante em todas as resoluções.

Então você também pode usar: '`right:15px`' ou outro valor que dê o resultado desejado.

Comment: @Cersuumt Dei uma editada na sua resposta porque ela me parece ser uma resposta de fato, e não apenas um comentário. :)

Comment: Ok, obrigado =D Também melhorei um pouco a explicação, havia esquecido de mencionar o propósito do 'px'

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, @celsomtrindade. A uns dias atrás também tomei essa "solução", estou colocando o css inline `right: x%` em cada dropdown que faço, porém não pretendo continuar isso por muito tempo.